# How to create an html element and make it stay in the DOM even after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website that contains an html form.
I coded in JavaScript that when the form is filled and when the button "Publier" is clicked,
it creates a table with the information filled in the form.
It works, but, when I reload the page, the tables disappear.
How can I make the tables stay on the page even after reloading it ?

Here are my html and JavaScript codes :

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');

button.addEventListener("click", () => {

  let nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
  let adresse = document.getElementById("adresse").value;
  let capacite = document.getElementById("capacite").value;
  let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  let heure1 = document.getElementById("heure1").value;
  let heure2 = document.getElementById("heure2").value;


  if (nom !== "" && adresse !== "" && capacite !== "" && phone !== "" && heure1 !== "" && heure2 !== "") {
    console.log("");
    btn.style.display = "block";
    party.style.display = "none"
    let table = document.createElement('table');

    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(table);

    let row_1 = document.createElement('tr');
    let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_1.innerHTML = "Nom de la pool party";
    let heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_2.innerHTML = "heure de début";
    let heading_3 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_3.innerHTML = "heure de fin";
    let heading_4 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_4.innerHTML = "adresse";
    let heading_5 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_5.innerHTML = "capacité";
    let heading_6 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_6.innerHTML = "téléphone";

    row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_3);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_4);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_5);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_6);
    table.appendChild(row_1);


    let row_2 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_2_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_1.innerHTML = nom;
    let row_2_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_2.innerHTML = heure1;
    let row_2_data_3 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_3.innerHTML = heure2;
    let row_2_data_4 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_4.innerHTML = adresse;
    let row_2_data_5 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_5.innerHTML = capacite;
    let row_2_data_6 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_6.innerHTML = phone;

    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_1);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_2);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_3);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_4);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_5);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_6);
    table.appendChild(row_2);

    alert("Formulaire envoyé !")
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="party">
  <h1>Publication</h1>
  <div>
    <label for="nom">Nom de la pool party :</label>
    <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="nom de la pool party" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="adresse">Adresse de la pool party :</label>
    <input type="text" id="adresse" name="adresse" placeholder="adresse de la pool party" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="capacite">Capacité d'acceuil :</label>
    <input type="text" id="capacite" name="capacite" placeholder="capacité d'acceuil de la pool party" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="phone">Numéro de téléphone (facultatif) :</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="numéro de téléphone" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="heure1">Heure de début :</label>
    <input type="text" id="heure1" name="heure1" placeholder="10h15" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="heure2">Heure de fin :</label>
    <input type="text" id="heure2" name="heure2" placeholder="20h15" required>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Publier</button>
</div>
```

Comment: As you may have noticed, when you refresh the page the results of your javascript code are discarded and the code must run again. This is an inherent limitation of your code running on the client. You may look into server side rendering instead, where the server will run the code to generate the tables BEFORE serving the page to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to add rows, refresh and still have the same table and rows and be able to add even more rows after that and still have them show upon another reload: https://jsfiddle.net/dp8uLez5/11/

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');
const storageKey = "local_v2"

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  event.preventDefault()
  let nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
  let adresse = document.getElementById("adresse").value;
  let capacite = document.getElementById("capacite").value;
  let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  let heure1 = document.getElementById("heure1").value;
  let heure2 = document.getElementById("heure2").value;

  if (nom !== "" && adresse !== "" &&
    capacite !== "" && phone !== "" &&
    heure1 !== "" && heure2 !== "") {

    let btn = document.createElement('btn');
    let party = document.createElement('party');
    btn.style.display = "block";
    party.style.display = "none"
    let table = makeTable((document.querySelector('table') === null));

    let row_2 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_2_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_1.innerHTML = nom;
    let row_2_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_2.innerHTML = heure1;
    let row_2_data_3 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_3.innerHTML = heure2;
    let row_2_data_4 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_4.innerHTML = adresse;
    let row_2_data_5 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_5.innerHTML = capacite;
    let row_2_data_6 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_6.innerHTML = phone;

    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_1);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_2);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_3);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_4);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_5);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_6);
    table.appendChild(row_2);

    let rows = (localStorage.getItem(storageKey) || '') + '¬' + row_2.innerHTML
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, rows);
    alert("Formulaire envoyé !")
  }
});


function makeTable(isfirstTime) {
  let table = null;
  if (isfirstTime) {
    table = document.createElement('table');
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(table);
    let row_1 = document.createElement('tr');
    let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_1.innerHTML = "Nom de la pool party";
    let heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_2.innerHTML = "heure de début";
    let heading_3 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_3.innerHTML = "heure de fin";
    let heading_4 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_4.innerHTML = "adresse";
    let heading_5 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_5.innerHTML = "capacité";
    let heading_6 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_6.innerHTML = "téléphone";

    row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_3);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_4);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_5);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_6);
    table.appendChild(row_1);

  } else {
    table = document.querySelector('table');
  }
  return table;
}


$(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem(storageKey) !== null) {
    let table = makeTable(true);
    var str = localStorage.getItem(storageKey)
    for (var i = 0; i < str.split('¬').length; i++) {
      if ((str.split('¬')[i] !== '')) {
        let arow = document.createElement('tr')
        arow.innerHTML = str.split('¬')[i]
        table.appendChild(arow);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. I want that it adds tables, here, it just adds rows.        Can you correct it please ?

Comment: so save multiple tables one under each other? ... personally i think that might look strange but ok ....

Comment: It's like everybody can add tables and everybody can see all the tables that have been created.

Answer (score 0):

Add the event.preventDefault() to your .addEventListener("click", function(event){

Comment: You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: Aquiles Bailo,  Thanks for your answer. So I add event.preventDefault() in first in my  .addEventListener("click", function(event){, before the lines where it create the table ?

Comment: Answer needs to be formatted and more detailed with code-style

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage, to store form inputs and retrieve it on page load.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

As AlekseyVY states, local storage is the way to go, see an example here using your code above:

https://jsfiddle.net/2g8nd7hy/2/

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');
const storageKey = "local"
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    event.preventDefault()
  let nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
  let adresse = document.getElementById("adresse").value;
  let capacite = document.getElementById("capacite").value;
  let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  let heure1 = document.getElementById("heure1").value;
  let heure2 = document.getElementById("heure2").value;

  if (nom !== "" && adresse !== "" &&
    capacite !== "" && phone !== "" &&
    heure1 !== "" && heure2 !== "") {
    let btn = document.createElement('btn');
    let party = document.createElement('party');
    btn.style.display = "block";
    party.style.display = "none"
    let table = document.createElement('table');

    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(table);

    let row_1 = document.createElement('tr');
    let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_1.innerHTML = "Nom de la pool party";
    let heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_2.innerHTML = "heure de début";
    let heading_3 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_3.innerHTML = "heure de fin";
    let heading_4 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_4.innerHTML = "adresse";
    let heading_5 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_5.innerHTML = "capacité";
    let heading_6 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_6.innerHTML = "téléphone";

    row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_3);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_4);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_5);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_6);
    table.appendChild(row_1);


    let row_2 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_2_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_1.innerHTML = nom;
    let row_2_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_2.innerHTML = heure1;
    let row_2_data_3 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_3.innerHTML = heure2;
    let row_2_data_4 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_4.innerHTML = adresse;
    let row_2_data_5 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_5.innerHTML = capacite;
    let row_2_data_6 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_6.innerHTML = phone;

    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_1);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_2);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_3);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_4);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_5);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_6);
    table.appendChild(row_2);
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey,
      document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].outerHTML.toString())
    alert("Formulaire envoyé !")
  }

});
var support = (function() {
  if (!window.DOMParser) return false;
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  try {
    parser.parseFromString('x', 'text/html');
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})();
var stringToHTML = function(str) {
  // If DOMParser is supported, use it
  if (support) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
    return doc.body;
  }
  // Otherwise, fallback to old-school method
  var dom = document.createElement('div');
  dom.innerHTML = str;
  return dom;
};
$(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem(storageKey) !== null) {
    var str = localStorage.getItem(storageKey)
    var doc = stringToHTML(str)
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(doc);
  }
});
```

[image: Example]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but it still doesn't work :<

Comment: I tested the js fiddle I gave you works ok on my PC....when you say doesn't work can you elaborate a bit, does the js fiddle I made not work for you, or is it not working when you apply it on your site/locally, do you have a browser extension or something that clear cache?

Comment: I update the answer showing the recording I took of the js fiddle working ...is this not what you found when you tried it ?

Comment: Actually, it is what find but it just does it for the first table created.             If you add a second one and you reload the page there will be just the first one.

Comment: Do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: sure I can give you a solution for that, did you want to append the second table to the first or simply override it?

Comment: Thanks, Yes I want the second tableto appear in addition to the first.

Answer (score 0):

so like this then: https://jsfiddle.net/o3Ldx1z7/14/

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');
const storageKey = "local_v3.1"

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  event.preventDefault()
  let nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
  let adresse = document.getElementById("adresse").value;
  let capacite = document.getElementById("capacite").value;
  let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  let heure1 = document.getElementById("heure1").value;
  let heure2 = document.getElementById("heure2").value;

  if (nom !== "" && adresse !== "" &&
    capacite !== "" && phone !== "" &&
    heure1 !== "" && heure2 !== "") {

    let btn = document.createElement('btn');
    let party = document.createElement('party');
    btn.style.display = "block";
    party.style.display = "none"
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(table);
    let row_1 = document.createElement('tr');
    let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_1.innerHTML = "Nom de la pool party";
    let heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_2.innerHTML = "heure de début";
    let heading_3 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_3.innerHTML = "heure de fin";
    let heading_4 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_4.innerHTML = "adresse";
    let heading_5 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_5.innerHTML = "capacité";
    let heading_6 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_6.innerHTML = "téléphone";

    row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_3);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_4);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_5);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_6);
    table.appendChild(row_1);

    let row_2 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_2_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_1.innerHTML = nom;
    let row_2_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_2.innerHTML = heure1;
    let row_2_data_3 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_3.innerHTML = heure2;
    let row_2_data_4 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_4.innerHTML = adresse;
    let row_2_data_5 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_5.innerHTML = capacite;
    let row_2_data_6 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_6.innerHTML = phone;

    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_1);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_2);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_3);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_4);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_5);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_6);
    table.appendChild(row_2);
    let tables = ''

    document.querySelectorAll('table')
      .forEach(function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
        tables += item.outerHTML;
        return item.outerHTML;
      })
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, tables);
    alert("Formulaire envoyé !")
  }
});
var support = (function() {
  if (!window.DOMParser) return false;
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  try {
    parser.parseFromString('x', 'text/html');
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})();
var stringToHTML = function(str) {
  // If DOMParser is supported, use it
  if (support) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
    return doc.body;
  }
  // Otherwise, fallback to old-school method
  var dom = document.createElement('div');
  dom.innerHTML = str;
  return dom;
};

$(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem(storageKey) !== null) {
    var str = localStorage.getItem(storageKey)
    var doc = stringToHTML(str)
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(doc);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for having spent your time on it bro, it works well.                       I have just a last request, do you know how to make that each time a table is created it appears above the last table and not below ?

Answer (score 0):

I won't lie it was fiddly to get this to work but here it is...

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');
const storageKey = "local_v3.7"

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  event.preventDefault()
  let nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
  let adresse = document.getElementById("adresse").value;
  let capacite = document.getElementById("capacite").value;
  let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  let heure1 = document.getElementById("heure1").value;
  let heure2 = document.getElementById("heure2").value;

  if (nom !== "" && adresse !== "" &&
    capacite !== "" && phone !== "" &&
    heure1 !== "" && heure2 !== "") {
    let btn = document.createElement('btn');
    let party = document.createElement('party');
    btn.style.display = "block";
    party.style.display = "none"
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    const ref = document.getElementById("res");

    ref.insertBefore(table, ref.children[0]);

    let row_1 = document.createElement('tr');
    let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_1.innerHTML = "Nom de la pool party";
    let heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_2.innerHTML = "heure de début";
    let heading_3 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_3.innerHTML = "heure de fin";
    let heading_4 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_4.innerHTML = "adresse";
    let heading_5 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_5.innerHTML = "capacité";
    let heading_6 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_6.innerHTML = "téléphone";

    row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_3);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_4);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_5);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_6);
    table.appendChild(row_1);

    let row_2 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_2_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_1.innerHTML = nom;
    let row_2_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_2.innerHTML = heure1;
    let row_2_data_3 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_3.innerHTML = heure2;
    let row_2_data_4 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_4.innerHTML = adresse;
    let row_2_data_5 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_5.innerHTML = capacite;
    let row_2_data_6 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_6.innerHTML = phone;

    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_1);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_2);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_3);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_4);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_5);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_6);
    table.appendChild(row_2);
    let tables = ''

    document.querySelectorAll('table')
      .forEach(function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
        tables += item.outerHTML;
        return item.outerHTML;
      })
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, tables);
    alert("Formulaire envoyé !")
  }
});
var support = (function() {
  if (!window.DOMParser) return false;
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  try {
    parser.parseFromString('x', 'text/html');
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})();
var stringToHTML = function(str) {
  // If DOMParser is supported, use it
  if (support) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
    return doc.body;
  }
  // Otherwise, fallback to old-school method
  var dom = document.createElement('div');
  dom.innerHTML = str;
  return dom;
};

$(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem(storageKey) !== null) {
    var str = localStorage.getItem(storageKey)
    var doc = stringToHTML(str)
    var tbls = Array.from(doc.children)
    for (var count = 0; count < tbls.length; count++) {
      //console.log(count + ': ' + tbls[count].innerHTML);
      document.getElementById('res').appendChild(tbls[count]);
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7sce9gx/38/

Please not your need this bit of additional HTML to hold the tables

```html
<div id="res">
</div>
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: glad I could help, mind accepting the answer please, I need the points you see